# Javascript regext time format detection

Tags: javascript, regex, time

I am trying to write a bit of JS code to validate a time entered into an input field in the 24hr format. I would like to be able to detect HH:MM, HHMM and HMM and reject anything else. I also would like to detect if the time is possible withing 24hrs - e.g. to reject 26:70 and the likes and this is what I currently don't manage to do:

```
function validateTime(rawtime) {
 var timeregex = new RegExp('([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]');
 var timeregex4 = new RegExp('([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3])[0-5][0-9]');
 var timeregex3 = new RegExp('[0-9][0-5][0-9]');
 var numeric = new RegExp('^[0-9]+$');

 if (numeric.test(rawtime))
  { 

    if ((rawtime.length == 4) && (timeregex4.test(rawtime))){
        document.getElementById("fdbk").innerHTML ="time with 4 digits";
        }
    else if ((rawtime.length == 3) && (timeregex3.test(rawtime))){
      document.getElementById("fdbk").innerHTML ="time with 3 digits";
    }
   }
   else if (timeregex.test(rawtime)) {
    document.getElementById("fdbk").innerHTML ="time with :";

  }
}
```

[Jsbin Example](https://jsbin.com/moxurakaqu/edit?js,console,output)

Comment: What if 2300 is not 23pm but 23 minutes after midnight (so MMHH instead of HHMM) ? It is not so simple to detect the format from the input string.

Comment: In what format in the world does `2300` represent 23 minutes past midnight?

Comment: It was just an example. It happens that this kind of question is asked also for other formats. So for example instead of hours and minutes you use days and months 0102 is first february for italians and second january for english people

Comment: Please clarify your expectations of the use of 24 hour notation. 00:00 to 24:00, or standard military communication regulations 00:00 to 23:59, or U.S. Navy and U.S. Marine Corps regulations 00:01 to 24:00? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO 0102 is first of Feburary for most sane countries, although personally I would write 1/Feb (or 2/Jan) to avoid ambiguity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not too sure what the problem is, it's easy ^_^

```
var timeregex = /^([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):?([0-5][0-9])$/;
```

Now match it...

```
var match = rawtime.match(timeregex);
```

And you get...

```
var hours = parseInt(match[1],10),
    minutes = parseInt(match[2],10);
```

Done?

Comment: @Mike [Yes it does](http://regexr.com/3bm6a). You just need to learn how to use regex tools properly :p

Comment: The 24-hour notation unambiguously distinguishes between midnight at the start (00:00) and end (24:00) even if style guides and military communication regulations in some English-speaking countries discourage the use of 24:00 even in the 24-hour notation. Sometimes the use of 00:00 is instead avoided. The OP's requirements are not clear on this and hence this may or may not be the correct answer. :)

Comment: @Niet - You are right about my lack of knowledge about regex - hence my questions here ;) - however shouldn't your orginal regex varibale also have the /gm modifiers ? I did add them to my example and now it [catches](https://jsbin.com/xebugupehi/edit?js,console,output) all the desired time "formats". So thank you.

Comment: @Mike The regex in this code assumes that `rawtime` is literally `"0123"` - a string that contains your time and only your time, and extracting the hours and minutes from it.

Answer (score 0):

Heres a simple function (not using RegEx) that validates the time formats you've requested.

```
function valTime(time) { 
    var len = time.length,
        hour,
        mins;

    if(len == 5) { //HH:MM
        var spl = time.split(':');
        if(!$.isArray(spl)) { return false; } //Not an array
        hour = spl[0];
        mins = spl[1];
    }
    if(len == 4) { //HHMM
        hour = time[0] + time[1];
        mins = time[2] + time[3];
    } 
    if(len == 3) { //HMM
        hour = time[0];
        mins = time[1] + time[2];
    }

    if(+hour <= 23 && +mins <= 59) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```